# The land-owners of yore

Tags: riddle, word

> As an animal I was
>   once named by a roe
>   On other occasions
>   I shift to and fro
>
> I live with my brethren,
>   together we stand,
>   If given free reign
>   We'll take o'er the land
>
> I'm plucky, I'm friendly
>   I have many names
>   I'm thorny, I'm driven
>   and girls use me for games
>
> My homophonous friend
>   can create quite a treat
>   Just give it some friends
>   and add lots of heat.

What am I?  Please explain.

Comment: googling variations on 'girls games' is wildly depressing

Comment: I'll give you a hint on that one.  Consider youth.

Comment: This one ended up being solved as quickly as I feared.  Oh well, I enjoyed creating it. :)

Comment: It's a good one, in my opinion. All the clues make sense but none of them are (to my thinking) too direct.

Comment: It took me 20 minutes to come up with a title that didn't give it away too much :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are a

> Flower

Paragraph 1:

> The skunk from Bambi was named Flower, by Bambi the roe deer

Paragraph 2:

> Flowers grow in bunches, and spread almost indefinitely from generation to generation if not controlled

Paragraph 3:

> You pluck flowers, give them to friends (typically those of romantic interest), there are many species of flowering plant
> Some are thorny, not sure on the 'driven' part
> Games such as 'He loves me, he loves me not' require a flower

Paragraph 4:

> Flour can be used to make a cake!

Comment: This answer needs a lot more explanation before it can be considered.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to get it in before someone else submitted it. Sorry!

Comment: Hah!  Thanks for solving paragraph 1!

Comment: The last paragraph was the one that gave the solution away. The first one was the hardest! Good traditional-style riddle, thanks!

Comment: Amusing.  I added the 3rd paragraph, last, and feared it would be the one to give it away. - oh and Driven refers to their drive to get to the sunlight, before their brethren.

Comment: Do you have an explanation for the title? I can't work out whether I'm missing something or the questioner is, but the "logical" explanation I can think of for the title is factually inaccurate :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop It was a bit of a stretch, but I needed a title.  It's referring to land being under the control of plants and flowers until force-ably removed by something else.

Comment: Ah, good. I read it as being specifically about there being plants on land before there were animals (in which case my objection would be that there were animals on land before there were any flowering plants at all). But if you mean wilderness in general then I get it now :-)